# Why does ObjectOutputStream.writeObject not take a Serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, marker-interfaces

Why does [`ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Object o)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29) not take a [`Serializable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)? Why is it taking an `Object`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is because `writeObject` in `ObjectOutputStream` overrides [the method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutput.html#writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29) in [the `ObjectOutput` interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutput.html) which does not require that the object be `Serializable`.

The `ObjectOutput` interface specifies methods that allow objects to be written to a stream or underlying storage, but this may be achieved by a process other than serialization. The `ObjectOutputStream` implements this functionality, but requires serializable objects. However, it cannot modify the signature of the interface that it implements.

Comment: @Joachim What process other than synchronization allows objects to be written to a stream ?

Comment: please see my comment above . can you throw some light here ?

Comment: @Geek: anything, really. JAXB for example could be used.

Comment: Wouldn't a more proper implementation of this be to have written a `writeSerializable` method for the ObjectOutputStream that takes a `Serializable` instead of an `Object` and then calls the `writeObject` method?

Answer (score 5):

It should be `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(serializable)` rather than `ObjectOutputStream. writeObject(Object)`. It is a proper use case where a marker interface like `Serializable` should have been used but unfortunately not. This would have made it possible the very real benefit of compile-time type checking instead of failing at runtime if the object does not implement `Serializable` interface.

I would like to take this opportunity to mention what [Joshua Bloch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch) has mentioned in his book  [Effective java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683):

> A marker interface is an interface that contains no method
>   declarations, but merely designates (or “marks”) a class that
>   implements the interface as having some property. For example,
>   consider the Serializable interface. By implementing this interface, a
>   class indicates that its instances can be written to an
>   `ObjectOutputStream` (or “serialized”).
>
> In the case of the `Serializable` marker interface, the `ObjectOutputStream.write(Object)` method will fail if its argument does not
>   implement the interface. Inexplicably, the authors of the
>   `ObjectOutputStream` API did not take advantage of the `Serializable`
>   interface in declaring the write method. The method’s argument type
>   should have been `Serializable` rather than `Object`. As it stands, an
>   attempt to call `ObjectOutputStream.write` on an object that doesn’t
>   implement `Serializable` will fail only at runtime, but it didn’t have
>   to be that way.

Comment: I wonder how Bloch would respond to @AndyT's point.